# Dynamic Queries: Change table name in LINQ-to-Entities query

Tags: c#, .net, sql, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

Long time lurker, recent newcomer.

Been struggling a bit with queries with LINQ-to-Entities. I am using Visual Studio Express 2012 for Web and Entity Framework 4.0. Bear with me, it's a long explanation, to make sure i cover everything. Here's the situation:

I have a reusable .aspx page which acts as an Image Manager. It has an Ajax Toolkit FileUpload control and also a Repeater to display uploaded files. I access this Manager inside a Fancybox Modal Pop-up (iframe). It's opening URL has 2 parameters, an "ID" and a "Type".

In my ImageManager code-behind file, I have a function that binds all images to the repeater. In this function, I need to query a Database Table according to a "Type" (url parameter)... and that's exactly where the problem lies.

For the life of me, I don't know how to **write a dynamic LINQ-to-Entities query where the Table Name will change**, change according to a type...

Here is the function (the problematic part has comments):

```
private void BindImagesRepeater()
{
    DatabaseEntities db = new DatabaseEntities();
    FolderName = Session["foldername"].ToString();
    FolderPath = Server.MapPath("~") + "controls/" + FolderName + "/images";
    int itemid = Convert.ToInt32(Session["itemID"]);
    bool dirExist = Directory.Exists(@FolderPath + "/" + itemid);
    bool isSpotlight = false;
    string spotlightThumbPath = "";
    string thumbPath = "";
    string thumbname = "";
    string spotlightName = "";
    int thumbPosition = 0;
    int spotlightPosition = 0;
    int counter = 0;
    int rptrCount = 0;

    /////PART I DON'T QUITE UNDERSTAND
    var query = null; //I know this is impossible

    //select the Table to query
    switch (FolderName)
    {
        case "NewsManager":
            query = (from q in db.News Where q.ID == itemID select q);
            break;
        case "ProductsManager":
            query = (from q in db.Products Where ...
            break;
        case "ProjectsManager":
            query = ... db.Projects ...
            break;
        case "CalendarManager":
            query = ... db.Events ...
            break;
    }
    /////


    if (query.Count > 0)
    {
        var uniqueItm = query.First();

        isSpotlight = Convert.ToBoolean(uniqueItm.isSpotlight);
        thumbPath = uniqueItm.thumbnailPath;
        spotlightThumbPath = uniqueItm.spotlightThumbPath;

        thumbname = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(thumbPath);
        spotlightName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(spotlightThumbPath);

        if (dirExist)
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(FolderPath))
            {
                List<string> fileNames = GetFiles(FolderPath + "/" + itemid, "*.bmp|*.gif|*.jpg|*.jpeg|*.png", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
                var files = (from f in fileNames
                             where (!f.Contains("_Thumb")) && (!f.Contains("_SpotlightThumb"))
                             select new
                             {
                                 FilePath = f,
                                 FileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(f)
                             });

                if (files.Count() > 0)
                {
                    imagesRepeater.DataSource = files;
                    imagesRepeater.DataBind();

                    foreach (var img in files)
                    {

                        if (thumbPath != "" && thumbPath != null)
                        {
                            if (img.FileName.Contains(thumbname.Replace("_Thumb", "")))
                            {
                                thumbPosition = counter;
                            }
                        }

                        if (spotlightThumbPath != "" && spotlightThumbPath != null)
                        {
                            if (img.FileName.Contains(spotlightName.Replace("_SpotlightThumb", "")))
                            {
                                spotlightPosition = counter;
                            }
                        }

                        counter++;
                    }

                    if (isSpotlight)
                    {
                        foreach (RepeaterItem item in imagesRepeater.Items)
                        {
                            LinkButton spotlightLnkBtn = (LinkButton)item.FindControl("useAsThumbnailSpotlight");
                            spotlightLnkBtn.Visible = true;

                            if (thumbPath != "" && thumbPath != null)
                            {
                                if (rptrCount == thumbPosition)
                                {
                                    Label myThumbImage = (Label)item.FindControl("lblThumb");
                                    myThumbImage.Visible = true;
                                }
                            }

                            if (spotlightThumbPath != "" && spotlightThumbPath != null)
                            {
                                if (rptrCount == spotlightPosition)
                                {
                                    Label mySpotlightImage = (Label)item.FindControl("lblThumbSpotlight");
                                    mySpotlightImage.Visible = true;
                                }
                            }

                            rptrCount++;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        foreach (RepeaterItem item in imagesRepeater.Items)
                        {
                            if (thumbPath != "" && thumbPath != null)
                            {
                                if (rptrCount == thumbPosition)
                                {
                                    Label myThumbImage = (Label)item.FindControl("lblThumb");
                                    myThumbImage.Visible = true;
                                }
                            }

                            if (spotlightThumbPath != "" && spotlightThumbPath != null)
                            {
                                if (rptrCount == spotlightPosition)
                                {
                                    Label mySpotlightImage = (Label)item.FindControl("lblThumbSpotlight");
                                    mySpotlightImage.Visible = true;
                                }
                            }

                            rptrCount++;
                        }
                    }

                    uniqueItm.hasImages = true;
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    lblEmptyData.Visible = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    uniqueItm.hasImages = false;
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    lblEmptyData.Visible = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        lblEmptyData.Visible = true;
    }
}
```

I tried a few different things which were to no avail. I'm kind of stumped.
If I could NULL my "var query" that would settle it, but, of course, this is impossible, since this variable is implicitly-typed.

There must be a way to declare my variable other than using "var"...

If anyone has any idea, i would really appreciate. I hope i was concised enough.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By looking at how you use your query, it seems that your result is strongly typed
...

```
   var uniqueItm = query.First();

    isSpotlight = Convert.ToBoolean(uniqueItm.isSpotlight);
    thumbPath = uniqueItm.thumbnailPath;
    spotlightThumbPath = uniqueItm.spotlightThumbPath;
```

Every query should return result that has isSpotlight,thumbnailPath,spotlightThumbPath properties.
So why not create class for that:

```
public class MyQueryResult
{
  public bool isSpotlight{get;set;}
  public string thumbPath{get;set;}
  public string spotlightThumbPat{get;set;}
}
```

And type all of your queries to return objects of `MyQueryResult`

```
IQueryable<MyQueryResult> query = null; //This is now possible
//select the Table to query
switch (FolderName)
{
    case "NewsManager":
        query = from q in db.News Where q.ID == itemID 
                 select new MyQueryResult
                 {
                     isSpotLight=q.Something,
                     thumbPath = q.SomethingElse
                     etc...
                  }
        break;
    case "ProductsManager":
        query = (from q in db.Products Where ...
                 select new MyQueryResult
                 {
                     ---fill properties
                 }
        break;
     .... same thing for every case
  }

  var uniqueItm = query.FirstOrDefault();
  if (uniqueItm!=null)
  {
      ... do your thing with uniqueItm
  }
```

Comment: Oh my god, i didn't even know this was possible... that actually did the trick. :)

Thank you so much!!

I guess i just leveled up some more

Answer (score 0):

Actually I may have a solution on top of my head:

*Note: The solution are not tested.*

**First:**

In you case, `var result`, as you said, is implicitly typed. But in reality it is equivalent to `IEnumerable<object> result`. You could possibly use `IEnumerable<object> result = null` or `IEnumerable<object­>? result` instead, to accept a nullable value.

**Second:**

The second solution would consist of moving the query part into its own method, accepting a string parameter, returning an object collection or a nullable `IEnumerable<T>?` collection.

Regards!

Comment: The other solution solved my problem, but your solution makes sense also. I'll keep that in mind for later. Thank you for taking the time to find a solution.